# How to reduce extra response in signalr?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i did a chat project.
when anybody send message , i run this code to send message for all clients

```
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
  Clients.RecieveMessage(message);
}
```

but when 10 users send message at the same time , all clients get 10 responses.
how to optimize and reduce this responses ?

i executed following code

```
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
  Clients.RecieveMessage(message);
  Clients.RecieveMessage("Test");
}
```

but i got separate response for each message.
why SignalR doesn't combine these responses ? how to merge these messages into one response ?

Comment: "when 10 users send message at the same time , all clients get 10 responses" I guess this means that SignalR is doing its job correctly. What exactly do you want here? It's not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine these 10 different messages into one PersistentResponse, SignalR does not expose a way to do this. However, SignalR will automatically combine messages into a single PersistentResonse if the load is high enough to cause SignalR to pull multiple messages off the bus in one go.

Basically SignalR will reduce responses dynamically as needed to handle the load, and all of this should be completely transparent to a SignalR developer on both the server and client.

If the issue is that you think that clients using the long-polling transport are making requests too frequently, you could manually set a LongPollDelay. By default, long-polling clients will immediately reconnect once a message is received. With a non-zero LongPollDelay, the clients will reconnect after the delay has passed.

```
// Set long-polling reconnect delay to two seconds (stored in milliseconds)
SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport.LongPollDelay = 2000;
```

All messages that were sent during the delay will immediately be returned to the long-polling client in the subsequent request. This effectively turns the long-polling transport into a normal-polling transport if there are always messages sent during the LongPollDelay.

Naturally doing this will increase latency. I should also note that the LongPollDelay is only respected on the JavaScript client. So if you are using the .NET client, it will continue reconnect immediately after receiving a response even after changing this setting.